# Кэширование , как с ним бороться?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Доброе время суток.
Есть приложение которое загружает файлы на сервер и обрабатывает их.
Входные данных:

1. Кнопка загрузки и выбора файла.
2. Кнопка обработки файла.

Загрузка происходит Ajax на PHP фаил. Обработка(получение) XMLHttpRequest.

Суть проблемы: Кидаешь первый фаил(1) > обрабатываешь > выбираешь второй фаил(2) > обработка идет первого файла(1) (если нажать очистка кэша и аппаратная перезагрузка в браузере то берет второй фаил(2)).Как это побороть ?

Answer (score 0):

Берешь элемент инпута(тот, где файлики загружаешь) и после отправки в ставишь его value в null. Примерно так:

```
<input type="file" id="upload-files">

var el = document.querySelector('#upload-files');

$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(){
    el.value = null;
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: В данный момент не попробую , но как это может влиять ? не могли бы вы пояснить

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK сверху описана стандартная ситуация, когда мы очищаем кэш инпута(т.е. когда мы пытаемся загрузить один и тот же файл два раза подряд). Вообще конечно нужно больше кода с Вашей стороны(не очищаете переменную в которую присвиваете сам файл)